# Cannot call because it is a web method

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

***semi*** Resolved

It appears that the problem exists only when running in debug mode,
and only when running the commands thru the immediate / watch windows.

It just works this way.
Thanks for the answers.

---

I'm trying to consume a WCF service from .net 2.0 application.
I've added it as a web reference, the class appeared in the intellisense.
But, calling a method from the service returns an error of
 `Cannot call <method> because it is a web method`

**Service**

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirments(RequirmentsMode = ApsNetCompatibilityRequirments.Allowed)]
public class ConsumerResponder
{
    [OperationConract]
    public List<string> GetStrings(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return new List<string>{"hi"};
    }
}
```

**Services web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

    <system.ServiceModel>

        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="bh1">
                    <endpointDiscovery enabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>

            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <serviceMetada httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

        <services>
            <service name="Service.ConsumerResponder">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="bh1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Service.ConsumerResponder" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="wsHtppBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.ServiceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Usage**

```
using(ConsumerResponder cf = new ConsumerResponder())
{
    List<string> result = cf.GetStrings(1, true, 2, true, 3, true);
}
```

Tested from another places and in debug, and the service really returns values.

Comment: Just for grins - what happens if you add it as a service reference instead of web reference?

Comment: Not sure maybe you need to add `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />`

Comment: Can you give us the full details of the exception?  By any chance are you running in a partial  trust environment? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scf355x6(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thats the entire exception, no inner. I've added the exat code and web config i have.

Comment: What is the type of exception?  What is the ex.ToString()?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. it not really an exception. The result var just contains an empty list. When stopping there in debug ant executing `cf.GetStrings(1, true, 2, true, 3, true)` in the `watch` window, this message appears instead of the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ServiceContract] 
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirments(RequirmentsMode = ApsNetCompatibilityRequirments.Allowed)] public interface IConsumerResponder { 
    [OperationConract]   
    public List<string> GetStrings(int a, int b, int c);
}
```

---

```
public class ConsumerResponder:IConsumerResponder
{
   public List<string> GetStrings(int a, int b, int c) {  
       return new List<string>;     }
}
```

---

```
using(ConsumerResponder cf = new ConsumerResponder()) {    
 List<string> = cf.GetStrings(1,2,3); }
```

---

May be you can try this instead of the class.

Answer (score 0):

.Net 2.0 is the runtime. So I am assuming when you say .Net 2.0 Enterprise Edition, you are talking about the Visual Studio toolset (Visual Studio 2005).

---

WCF appeared for the first time in .Net 3.- so .Net 2.0 does not have WCF. However,you can install .Net 3.0 on top of your .Net 2.0 install and start using WCF.

Comment: the .net2 is only the **consumer** of the wcf service, which should expose its methods via a regular WS endpoint.

Comment: which version is ur web service using?

Comment: Yep, but does the version of visual studio matters? I'm on vs 2010, for both the cosumer and the service, while the service deployed to a server with 4.0 runtime, while the consumer deployed to a web server with 2.0 runtime.

Comment: Yes,But are you using it somewhat this way or similar ways: c# include header "using Myservice.servicename"
servicename objService = new servicename();   ?

Comment: yep, exactly like this. `servicename objService = new servicename(); `

Comment: hmmm... I dont think you can define the function here(IService1.cs) and you will have to define it in (Service1.svc). I am not sure about the code you are referring here.It should be as simple as:[ServiceContract] public class Service1 { [OperationContract] string GetData(int value); }

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [WSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Enhancements) on the .NET 2.0 side.

This link may help you:

[Interoperability between WCF and WSE 3.0](http://devlicio.us/blogs/ziemowit_skowronski/archive/2007/07/18/interoperability-between-wcf-and-wse-3-0.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately not available for me. wcf should be able to expose it's methods thru a regular ws interface.

Answer (score 0):

Can you atleast try to test your service with SOAP UI i.e. tool to test and services hosted on basic http binding. It will definitely give you idea if there is any problem?

Answer (score 0):

You spelt "Contract" wrong.

```
[OperationConract]
    public List<string> GetStrings(int a, int b, int c)
```

should be

```
[OperationContract]
    public List<string> GetStrings(int a, int b, int c)
```

Comment: a lil typo, while copying. Thanks though ;)

Comment: Ah ok, just wanted to make sure that it wasn't causing the problem. I've had things like that which have made me absolutely kick myself

Comment: @mwilson - I'm from England, it is an interchangeable spelling this side of the pond. See: http://grammarist.com/spelling/spelled-spelt/